# Changing Vim Keymapping for Ctrl + w

Tags: linux, vim, keymapping, chromebook

I use chromebook and for some reason everything opens in Chrome browser. I am fine using it that way but problem comes when I want to use vim.

In vim when I type :vsplit  it splits the screen vertically into two but to traverse between two splits I run Ctrl+W which should ideally work but since shell is in chrome browser, chrome asks for closing the tab.

So basically I want to override either the chrome browser mapping(but this will be tricky) or re-allocate/re-map Ctrl+Q/D for working as Ctrl+W.

Please assist.

Comment: You're not the first one who ever needed to change key bindings. Plenty of answers for vim key remapping. Search.

Comment: @karoly, I actually tried many approaches available and haven't written that I am the first one who needs to change key binding. I somehow dint find your answer professional enough but thanks for replying !!

Answer (score 2):

Adding this line to your `.vimrc` file may help:

```
map <C-Q> <C-W>
```

It will map <kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl + W</kbd>.

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, I tried this both from ./vimrc and adding the mapping command directly in the vi terminal. But it dint work. I also tried ":map <C-Q> dd" and this one worked perfectly fine..

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find a fix?